# How to retrieve specific csv column data when multiple conditions are given in Python?

Tags: python-3.8

Just like in MySQL query where we retrieve columns with conditions using *WHERE* clause, how can we do the same in Python? That too with a CSV file?

My CSV File contains data with attributes Name, Place and Color

1. Ruby,NewYork,Green
2. Casper,Seoul, Blue
3. Caroline,NewYork,Green

Now user is given choice to provide city and color name for search. If user input: City = NewYork and Color= Green, It should display

1. Ruby
2. Caroline.

How should I do it? I wrote a sample code but output is wrong.

```
import csv

class Test:
 
     def Display(Name,Place,Color):
        f = open('sample.csv')
        csv_f = csv.reader(f)
          for row in csv_f:
            if(row[1]==("NewYork") and row[2] ==("Green")):
            pass
          print(Name)  
  
Name,Place,Color = input("Enter Details: ").split()
Test.Display(Name,Place,Color)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following test object:

```
import csv

class Test:
    def display(self, name, place, color):
        with open('sample.csv') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            for row in csv_reader:
                if(row[1]==place and row[2] == color):
                    print(row[0])  

test = Test()
test.display("Name","NewYork","Green")
```

We have a Class with a member function for displaying the output.
You can first open the csv file and use the csv_file reference to create your reader in scope. Then you search each row's column for the given strings that you passed into the function.

It looks like you got into a bit of trouble trying to diagnose this one and have left test code in there that has been confusing you.

Comment: I tried working with your code since I understood the mistake I made, but while execution it gives me an error: IndexError: list index out of range in this line: if(row[1]==place and row[2] == color):

Comment: davbryn I think I've figured out what I missed. There was an extra blank line at last in csv file that gave an error. According to @Suit Boy Apps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585688/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-python-csv, I just added {if(len(i) < 1):
                continue } to the code and now it works perfectly fine. Thanks davbryn for helping!